# obtaining a uri via js

Tags: javascript, android

I am trying to get the uri of a selected file (tapped link on android).I'm only interested in links to pdf files (which are stored in the assets of a cordova app). My (very) long term goal (it seems) is to open the pdf file in a third party app. 
But to return to the point: I gathered (on S.O) these lines:

```
    $('A[href$=\\.pdf]').click(function() {
    var myfile = $()
        alert($('a', this).attr('href')); return false; 
});
```

but my alert returns "undefined" when I tap on:

```
<a href=" ../res/DOC140416-1.pdf" 
onclick="window.open(../res/DOC140416-1.pdf, _system); return false"> <span>my pdf test #012</span></a>
```

Can someone help out?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is...

```
$('a[href$=\\.pdf]').click(function() {
var myuri = this.href ;
```

Now on to the next step: using this variable to save the file on public directory...